# Angular-cli use proxy with dynamic port passed as a command-line argument

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli and to properly forward my requests to my backend using proxy I use the following config (proxy-config.json):

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://mybackend.com:1234",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

I serve the files using `ng serve --proxy-config proxy-config.json`

This works as expected, however I am using many different branches on different ports for testing purposes and I want to be able to easily change the backend port (in this case 1234) to something else without editing the file every time.

In an angularjs project with grunt I did something like `grunt serve:dev -r 1234` where -r meant the proxy port.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm also having this issue.

Comment: Hey! Not really, I wrote a script that changed the port number in the file, and then started the proxy server, since then the architecture of my software changed drastically so I no longer have this scenario.

Comment: You may use other proxy such as nginx to bind desired port to the fixed 1234 in the config. You can change the port in the nginx proxy config when you need to change the port IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a script instead of json as proxy.conf.js;

```js
//can be right next to angular.json
var process = require("process")
var BACKEND_PORT = process.env.BACKEND_PORT || 8080
console.log('backend port: ' + BACKEND_PORT)
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:" + BACKEND_PORT + "/api/",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG
```

To parametrize environment, you could call with something like;

```
ng serve ----configuration=confname #for instance production
```

which tells angular to load configurations from projectname.architect.serve.configurations.confname field inside angular.json. So you need to define it like;

```js
...{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "projectname": {
      ...
      "serve": {
        ...
        "configurations": {
          "confname": {
            "BACKEND_PORT": 80
          }
        },
        ...
      },
      ...
    }
  }
```